# MSAL library returns 403

Tags: android, outlook, microsoft-graph-api, azure-ad-msal

After configuring my app on `apps.dev.microsoft.com` I can login with an administrator account to the mobile application with MSAL. Other users get a `403 -Forbidden` when requesting data from Microsoft Graph.

What should be reconfigured for users to grant access?

App Registered Scopes:

```
User.ReadWrite
User.ReadBasic.All
Calendars.ReadWrite
Contacts.Read
```

Scope in Android App:

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/User.ReadWrite
https://graph.microsoft.com/User.ReadBasic.All
https://graph.microsoft.com/Calendars.ReadWrite
https://graph.microsoft.com/Contacts.Read
```

Requests made by App:

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/events
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/{user}/calendarview
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/events/{identifier}
```

Comment: Just to clarify, are saying MSAL is giving you a `403` or calls made to Graph are returning the `403`?

Comment: Call to Graph with token from MSAL return 403

Comment: Are you getting a `403` for each of the URIs you provided or just some of them (`/users`, `/events`, etc)? Also, can you add some example code showing how you're calling Graph?

Comment: I received 403 for /users, I need this data to proceed further

Comment: So `User.ReadBasic.All` should cover `/users`. It shouldn't be required for these scopes but have you tried doing an Admin Consent? See [v2 Endpoint and Admin Consent](http://massivescale.com/microsoft-v2-endpoint-admin-consent/) for details on how this works.

Comment: Thanks, but article did not help. I resetted all permissions on app.dev for my application and with it I can ask for users (1 step further). I  currenly have an issue with getting calendarview for specific user. Permissions:  Calendars.Read & Calendars.ReadWrite won't work

Comment: If you're trying to read a Calendar for someone other than the authenticated user then you need `Calendars.ReadWrite.Shared`. The `Shared` Calendar scopes support accessing all calendars the current user has access to.

Comment: Hi, thanks for helping. I think there was an issue with web configuration on app dev page. I remove all permission on it, and try to add more permissions than needed per request /users /events /calednarview and it started to work. Currently I am trying to remove not used permissions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suppose there was an issue with app dev web page or data was not propagated. I removed all delegated permissions from portal and app and with documentation added all permissions for my requests, even if documentation mentioned that I could choose only 1 from it. It worked for first request `/users` so I did it with another request. After checking that all request works in app I started to removed 'additional' permissions. It ended with only 3 permissions:

```
"https://graph.microsoft.com/User.ReadWrite",
"https://graph.microsoft.com/User.ReadBasic.All",
"https://graph.microsoft.com/Calendars.Read"
```